# Android: Send accelerometer data over UDP from thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, event-listener

Im trying to make app with MainActivity and SensorEventListener. The data from accelerometer will be saved in structure (class, two int variables). 
I created UDP client thread which runs after app launch. The UDP client send the two variables to remote server.

The problem is that I need to know when are the data from sensor refreshed and after that I send it over UDP client (another thread). Im new in android apps and java. 
It will be very helpful if you could give me some code samples how to do it.

**The code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

Button button;
String theLine = null;
public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.2.101"; // 'Within' the emulator!
public static final int SERVERPORT = 12345;


private static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;

public boolean bKeepRunning;

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;

Client client = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
}


public class Client extends Thread 
{

    bKeepRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        byte[] sendData = new byte[512];
        sendData =intToByteArray(angles.rolling, angles.pitching);
        sendData= reverseArray(sendData);
        InetAddress serverAddr = null;

        try{
            serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                }

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        try {
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

                while(bKeepRunning)
                {
                    socket.send(packet);
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                }
    }

    public void kill() 
    { 
        bKeepRunning = false;
    }


}   


public void addListenerOnButton() {

     final Context context = this;

     button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);

     }

     });
 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, UserSettingActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SETTINGS);
        break;


    case R.id.about_us:
        Intent j = new Intent(this, UserSettings.class);
        startActivityForResult(j, RESULT_SETTINGS);
        break;

    }

    return true;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_SETTINGS:
        showUserSettings();
        break;

    }

}



public void showUserSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.append("\n IP Address: " + sharedPrefs.getString("prefipaddress", "NULL"));

    builder.append("\n Port: " + sharedPrefs.getString("prefport", "NULL"));

    TextView settingsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textUserSettings);

    settingsTextView.setText(builder.toString());

        }

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    client = new Client();
    client.start();

}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    client.kill();
}

public static class angles
{
     static int rolling;
     static int pitching;
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final float alpha = (float) 0.9;
    float[] gravity = new float[3];
    float[] linear_acceleration = new float[3];

    TextView tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.roll);
    TextView tvY= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pitch);


    gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
    gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
    gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

    linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
    linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
    linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];

    String linear_acceleration0 = String.format("%.2f", linear_acceleration[0]).replace(",",".");
    String linear_acceleration1 = String.format("%.2f", linear_acceleration[1]).replace(",",".");
    String linear_acceleration2 = String.format("%.2f", linear_acceleration[2]).replace(",",".");

    linear_acceleration[0] = Float.parseFloat(linear_acceleration0);
    linear_acceleration[1] = Float.parseFloat(linear_acceleration1);
    linear_acceleration[2] = Float.parseFloat(linear_acceleration2);


    //float rotation = (float) (Math.atan2(linear_acceleration[0], linear_acceleration[1])/(Math.PI/180));

    float roll = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(linear_acceleration[0]/Math.sqrt(Math.pow(linear_acceleration[1], 2) + Math.pow(linear_acceleration[2], 2))));
    float pitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(linear_acceleration[1]/Math.sqrt(Math.pow(linear_acceleration[0], 2) + Math.pow(linear_acceleration[2], 2))));
    float yaw = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(linear_acceleration[0], 2) + Math.pow(linear_acceleration[1], 2))/linear_acceleration[2]));

    String roll_print = String.format("%.2f", roll);
    String pitch_print = String.format("%.2f", pitch);
    roll_print = roll_print.replace(",",".");
    pitch_print = pitch_print.replace(",",".");

    angles.rolling = Math.round(roll);
    angles.pitching = Math.round(pitch);

    tvX.setText(roll_print);
    tvY.setText(pitch_print);

}



@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public static byte[] intToByteArray(int intValue, int intValue1) {

    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    //b.order(ByteOrder..BIG_ENDIAN); // optional, the initial order of a byte buffer is always BIG_ENDIAN.
    b.putInt(intValue);
    b.putInt(intValue1);

    byte[] result = b.array();

    //for test
   int testnum= bytesToInt(result);
    System.out.println("reverse value is="+testnum);

return result;}

private static int bytesToInt(byte[] intBytes){
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(intBytes);
    return bb.getInt();}

public byte[] reverseArray(byte[] arr)
{
     int left = 0;
     int right = arr.length - 1;
     while (left < right) {
          byte temp = arr[left];
          arr[left] = arr[right];
          arr[right] = temp;
          left++;
          right--;
     }
     return arr;}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution here: http://techtej.blogspot.sk/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html

1. Create worker thread
2. Call the Looper methods
3. Create a Handler to recieve the Messages

Answer (score 0):

Well The best thing to do is go to the official google android API and check the object documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onSensorChanged(android.hardware.SensorEvent)

For some more guidance I added some great websites with tutorials (but google can also serve you well) - 

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSensor/article.html

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125

Comment: I know this articles. But Im searching for something with UDP connection and reading sensor data from another thread.